# Составить программу расчета функции, по минимуму использовать встроенные методы и функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, python-3.5

Заданные значения х, точность эпсилон. Составить программу расчета функции y с точностью эпсилон, используя рекурсивный и итерационный алгоритмы решения задачи.
Определить, какое количество членов ряда необходимо просуммировать для достижения указанной точности (сравнить результат суммирования со значением стандартной функции).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, что пока получилось:

```
def NonRec(x, eps):
    s=1
    term=1
    i=0
    while (abs(term) > eps):
        term=term*(x/(i+1))
        s+=term
        i+=1
    return s
```

Comment: Не смог реализовать рекурсивный алгоритм нахождения косинуса, поэтому открыл [новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908267). Возможно вам будет интересно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нерекурсивная функция:

```
import math

def cosine(x, eps=1e-5):
    res = 1
    i = 1
    x = x * math.pi / 180.    
    while True:
        delta = (x**(2*i) / math.factorial(2*i))
        res += (-1)**i * delta
        i += 1
        if delta <= eps:
            return res, i
```

Пример:

```
In [50]: res, n = cosine(123, eps=1e-6)

In [51]: print(res, n)
-0.544639044595552 8
```