# Условие выхода из рекурсивной функции (считаем косинус через ряд Маклорена)

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика, рекурсия

Отвечая на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908177), я попытался реализовать *рекурсивную* функцию для вычисления косинуса при помощи ряда Маклорена *до указанной точности (эпсилон)*.

[Формула](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8F%D0%B4_%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0#%D0%A0%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никак не могу придумать, как реализовать проверку точности для завершения/выхода из рекурсии.

Вот набросок функции без проверки точности:

```
import math

def cosine_rec(x, i=0, err=10**9, eps=1e-5):
    if i < 1:
        return 1
    # как проверить текущую ошибку ???
    res = (-1)**i * (x**(2*i) / math.factorial(2*i))
    return res + cosine_rec(x, i+1, err=err, eps=eps)
```

PS с итеративным алгоритмом все просто, поэтому нерекурсивные решения прошу не предлагать.

Comment: Поскольку ряд знакоперемменный, то достаточно сравнивать текущий член с точностью (по абсу есссно). Как меньше - так стоп.

Comment: @Akina, не совсем понял ... Сравнивать с чем? Если с эталонным значением косинуса то нужно сравнивать сумму ряда. Как её получить находясь в рекурсивной функции?

Comment: Русским вроде по белому пишу: "текущий член с точностью". Где тут написано про какой-то эталонный косинус?

Comment: @Akina, спасибо!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def cosine_rec(x, i=0, err=10**9, eps=1e-5):
    if i < 0:
        return 1
    res = x**(2*i) / math.factorial(2*i)
    if res <= eps:
        return (-1)**i * res
    return (-1)**i * res + cosine_rec(x, i+1, err=err, eps=eps)
```

Comment: Спасибо за предложенный ответ, но что-то у меня всегда в результате `1` получается вне зависимости от переданного `x`??

Comment: @MaxU `if i < 0:` - ?

Comment: вы можете привести код функции целиком?

Comment: @MaxU Как делается самый первый вызов функции?

Comment: `cosine_rec(123, i=0, err=10**9, eps=1e-5)` Параметр `err` можно выкинуть за ненадобностью

Comment: @MaxU У Вас же `i` первой строчкой сравнивается с единицей, а не с нулем.

Comment: @MaxU Вам не нужен  `if i < 1:      return 1` из кода вопроса - этот случай обрабатывается по общим правилам

Comment: да, что-то я сегодня не в форме... Спасибо!!!